# I am trying to display my findall method in a listbox, only showing numbers 1-10

Tags: css, .net, findall

private void MinNumb(List intList)
{

```
        intList.FindAll(x => x < 11 && x > 0);
        intList.ForEach(x => listBox3.Items.Add(x));
    }
```

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List intList = new List();

```
        ReadList(intList);

        MinNumb(intList);
    }
```

Comment: What do you have in `intList`? And what result were you expecting?

Comment: intList is my list I created for a StreamReader Inputfile.  It is a text file with a lot of integers and that is displaying fine, however I have a secondary button that when clicked am trying to call my method (minNumb) using the findall that will display in my listbox2 numbers from my text file that are only 1-10

Comment: public void ReadList(List<int> intList)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("numbers.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    intList.Add(int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()));
                }

                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }